# Bounded logarithmic function

Tags: probability-theory, functions, optimization

I am trying to find any function that it grows logarithmically up to a certain point, and after that point it remains constant.
Can anyone help me with that

Comment: Does the function have any other properties? Otherwise, why not just define the function piecewise? Also, what is your domain?

Comment: Basically I am trying to find a policy in a decision problem that makes the cost function to increase logarithmically up to a certain time, but after that time the policy always makes the correct decision and thus the cost function stop increasing and it remains finite and thus bounded.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since the conditions are rather mild, you can try

$$\text{For}\;\;x>0:\;\;f(x)=\begin{cases}\log x&,\;\;x\le k\\{}\\{}\log k&,\;\;x>k\end{cases}$$

The above function is even continuous, logarithmic up to certain point $\;x=k\;$ , and then a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the stereographic projection, that climbs at a kind of logarithmic rate but ever slower as it approaches a maximal value that it never quite reaches or exceeds.

Draw a unit circle on the Cartesian coordinates, define a point p on the x axis that can be any value x, then define a projection from the zenith of the unit circle, i.e. z = (0,1), to point p, and mark the point on the unit circle where it crosses the line zp. The angle of that projection from the vertical (x=0) is bounded from zero (pointing straight down) to 90 degrees pointing at infinity!

The stereographic mapping s(x) is that angle as a function of x, where x goes out to infinity but the angle never reaches or exceeds 90 deg from the vertical.

It squashes infinity into a finite bounded range with a single continuous (not piecewise) smooth function that does just what you want.